# How to apply validation on a string variable so that it accept only alphabetic data from the user?

Tags: c++, io

I want to make the user enter alphabetic data only not any numeric or special character data. So how do I apply the validation? For example, in the following code, I want the user to input name and name doesn't include any number or special character. I want to make it accept only alphabetic data.

```
int main()
{
   string str;
   cout<<"Enter your name: ";
   cin>>str;
}
```

Comment: use getch() to read an one character, in loop

Comment: When the string is read, loop over every character in it and check if it is alphabetic.   If non-alphabetic data is found, you have choices such as ignoring it, emitting an error message, discarding the whole string, etc.   It is not possible to make the user do anything without dedicated hardware support (e.g. to give an electric jolt if the user's finger touches a non-alphabetic key).

Comment: @Peter Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `ctype.h`   or `cctype`
[Functions to determine the type contained in character data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte)

**Ex:**  It accepts only `alphabetic` nothing else even `space`

```
std::string ui; // user input
std::getline( std::cin, ui );

bool vi = true; // validate input
for( const char& chr : ui ){
    if( !std::isalpha( chr ) ){
        vi = false;
        break;
    }
}

if( vi ){
    std::cout << "okay\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "NOT!\n";
}
```

the other one is to use `std::regex`
[Regular expressions library (C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

**Ex:**  Likewise

```
std::string ui; // user input
std::getline( std::cin, ui );

bool vi = true; // validate input

//    for( const char& chr : ui ){
//        if( !std::isalpha( chr ) ){
//            vi = false;
//            break;
//        }
//    }

vi = std::regex_match( ui, std::regex( "[A-Za-z]+" ) );

if( vi ){
    std::cout << "okay\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "NOT!\n";
}
```

You can find what you need based on these functions or use `regexes`

```
isalnum  
isalpha
islower 
isupper 
isdigit 
isxdigit 
iscntrl 
isgraph
isspace 
isblank
isprint
ispunct
```

And a Third way can be use of `std::string::find`

Ex:

```
std::string ui; // user input
std::getline( std::cin, ui );

bool vi = true; // validate input

// find
// rfind
// find_first_of
// find_first_not_of
// find_last_of
// find_last_not_of

const char* not_valid_input = "!@#$%^&*()_+,.";
while( *not_valid_input ){

    if( ui.find( *not_valid_input ) < ui.size() ){
        vi = false;
        break;
    }

    ++not_valid_input;
}


if( vi ){
    std::cout << "okay\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "NOT!\n";
}
```

Also a fourth way can be to use `std::find_if`, but the **negate version**

```
std::string ui; // user input
std::getline( std::cin, ui );

bool vi = true; // validate input

vi = std::find_if_not( ui.begin(), ui.end(), ::isalpha ) == ui.end();

if( vi ){
    std::cout << "okay\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "NOT!\n";
}
```

---

NOTE: that the `c++11` for-loop in the EX: is equivalent to this:

```
for( unsigned index = 0; index < ui.size(); ++index ){
    if( !std::isalpha( ui[ index ] ) ){
        vi = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. In the first example, please explain what's happening at line 4? `for( const char& chr : ui )` and what's *chr* in `if( !std::isalpha( chr ) ){
        vi = false;
        break;
    }` ?

Comment: @IBTEHAAJSHAHID Do you mean `for( const char& chr : ui )`

Comment: i don't understand what's happening at `for( const char& chr : ui )`

Comment: in the first place before the colon, you initialized chr, right?

Comment: what's the purpose of colon?

Comment: @IBTEHAAJSHAHID Okay. It is a `c++11` for loop over the **ui** that has type of `std::string`. Since `std::string` is a list of `char` so you can loop over it. And try to validate all `char` in your **ui** variable.

Comment: Got it.. Thank you very much

Comment: @IBTEHAAJSHAHID you are welcome. See the NOTE at the end of the answer I just added to

Comment: sure... understood.

Comment: Note `std::isalpha` and `[A-Za-z]` may not be equivalent, depending on locale.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks. Of course. But I just wanted to clarify these two. by an example

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered good practice to eschew loops whenever they can be replaced by a well named algorithm. See talks by Sean Parent with the mantra "no raw loops".

One way to do this here is to use [`std::all_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of/), which checks the string and will stop the loop as soon as the predicate returns false.

```
#include <cctype>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "enter a string using only characters from the alphabet.\n";

    cin >> s;

    if(all_of(begin(s), end(s), ::isalpha))
        cout << "all ok!!\n";
    else
        cout << "the string contains some non alpha characters.\n";
}
```

`all_of` is c++11 and later (do we really still need to add that disclaimer), however the function is trivial to implement if you don't have the standard library implementation available to you.

Also note this uses `cin` so only reads up to the first space if the line contains them. If you want to read the full line use `std::getline`

Comment: I guess std has no member "readline" in c++. Isn't it related to c#?

Comment: @Pual  `std` does not have `readline` . Can you give us a reference to it? or may you would want to say `getline`